# Combine 2 rows of different tables into one row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following row of my `table1` table:

| email | name | last_name | activated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex@ex.com | john | connor | 1 |

Which I can get using:

```
select email, name, last_name, activated from table1
where email = ex@ex.com
limit 1;
```

And then I have the other row of of my `table2`:

| status | end_period | qtd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1828232 | 20 |

Which I can get by using:

```
select status, end_period, qtd from table2
where email = ex@ex.com
limit 1;
```

Is there any way I can get the results into one line?
Like this:

| email | name | last_name | activated | status | end_period | qtd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex@ex.com | john | connor | 1 | 1 | 1828232 | 20 |

Ps: Both tables have an 'email' column, which is what I use to link the the row of one to another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: Please include the definitions for both tables.  What are the primary/foreign key relationships between these two tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use the 'email' column both tables have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a table join, in this case an `INNER JOIN` between `table1` and `table2` where the `email` column matches.

```sql
SELECT table1.email, table1.name, table1.last_name, table1.activated, table2.status, table2.end_period, table2.qtd
FROM `table1` AS table1
INNER JOIN `table2` AS table2
ON table1.email = table2.email
WHERE table1.email = 'ex@ex.com';
```

This results in your expected output:

| email | name | last_name | activated | status | end_period | qtd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex@ex.com | john | connor | 1 | 1 | 1828232 | 20 |

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is generally a not well defined thing.

Comment: Usually I use ```LIMIT 1``` to cap my result to one row if by any reason there's 2 users with the same email. I coded in PHP so that it checks if that user already exists and prevents that from occuring, but still is a safe measure is it not?